# Mean Independence and uncorrelated vs independence

Tags: probability, statistics, expected-value, independence, correlation

If we are given 2 RV's X and Y and find that they are both mean independent and uncorrelated, is it suffice to say that they are independent or are they any situations that this is not true? (Given that their expectations exist)

Comment: Please provide your thoughts. I think your are interested in that question and you´ve tried to solve it.

Comment: Since X and Y are mean independent, E[X|Y] = E[E[X|Y]] = E[X] (by the law of total expectation). And solely depends on Y or just a constant  -- E[X|Y] = f(y) or c. For correlation, (Assuming expectation of either is not 0 (forgot to mention this condition)), cov(X,Y) = 0 = E[XY] - E[X]E[Y]. Using mean independence,E[XY] = E[E[XY|Y]] = E[Y*E[X|Y]]  = E[Y * E[X]]. From here, I'm a bit stuck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard counterexample for "uncorrelated normals are not necessarily independent" works. Let $X$ be $N(0,1)$ and $Z$ be an independent coinflip $\pm 1,$ and let $Y=XZ.$ $X$ and $Y$ are mean-independent: $$E(X\mid Y) = E(Y\mid X) = E(X)=E(Y)=0.$$ (For instance $E(Y\mid X) = XP(Z=1)+(-X)P(Z=-1) = 0.)$

But they are not independent, since, e.g. $E(|Y|\mid X) = X$ which is generally not equal to $E(|Y|).$

Comment: Right, it seems pretty straightforward with the 0 mean cases where the covariance condition is abusable, but suppose we were given the conditions that E[X] and E[Y] were not 0 but also did exist, would the statement/situation change?

Comment: @HorsesPwn42 I don't think there is anything translation-sensitive about this example. Just let $(X,Y)\to (X+1,Y+1).$

Comment: This has the feature that $\mathrm{Var}(Y\mid X=x)=x^2$.  If instead you took the example of $X\sim N(0,1)$ and, given $X=x$, $Y \sim N(0,x^2)$, then you would have another example (note that the marginal distribution of this $Y$ would be more leptokurtic than a normal distribution)

Comment: @spaceisdarkgreen I see, thank you